# How to override search autocomplete model for Restricting only pick 5 item from collection

Tags: search, catalogsearch, search-terms

I need to restrict search autocomplete results.
I want to Restrict that only 5 item pic for query.

I did this Search/suggest.php controller.

But this is not a good way , i want to modify collection result.
How can i do this.

### I just override the controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Search\Controller\Ajax\Suggest" type="Embitel\Search\Controller\Ajax\Suggest"/>
</config>
```

### Controller

```
<?php
/**
* Ajax Search Controller
*/
namespace Embitel\Search\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Search\Model\AutocompleteInterface;

class Suggest extends \Magento\Search\Controller\Ajax\Suggest {

    /**
     * Maximum results to display 
     * Result is from (0 to 4) = 5
     * @var int
     */
    const MAX_RESULT_DISPLAY = 4;

    /**
     * Autocomplete
     *
     * @var  AutocompleteInterface
     */
    private $autocomplete;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param AutocompleteInterface $autocomplete
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        AutocompleteInterface $autocomplete
    ) {
        $this->autocomplete = $autocomplete;
        parent::__construct($context, $autocomplete);
    }

    /**
     * Render results
     *
     * @return Json
     */
    public function execute() {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('q', false)) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_url->getBaseUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $autocompleteItems = $this->autocomplete->getItems();
        $responseData = [];
        foreach ($autocompleteItems as $key=>$resultItem) {
            unset($resultItem['num_results']);
            $responseData[] = $resultItem->toArray();
            if($key == self::MAX_RESULT_DISPLAY){
                break;            
            }
        }
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($responseData);
        return $resultJson;
    }

}
```

This is working.

**But collection is coming in huge amount, that's why i want to restrict collection in model.**

Comment: First five items. Or you need more filter logic?

Comment: @vitoriodachef only first five item. by model

Comment: Is this Magento2?

Comment: @vitoriodachef yes...which code i used is now in question...by i want to do it by model.

Comment: If you necessarily want to do it by model you need to debug the vendor/magento/module-search/Model/Autocomplete.php and see from where the providers get their items. Or you could do an after plugin on the Autocomplete::getItems method.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the number of results is configurable from Admin. But is not working (known bug). Stores > Catalog > Catalog Search

Comment: @vitoriodachef we can do this by module-catalog-search/Model/Autocomplete/Dataproviders.php    Function name  getItems(). you can modify collection here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87024/discussion-between-vitoriodachef-and-deepak-rai).